# Unit Test Swift- casting view controller from storyboard not working

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, swift

I have written the below test case which worked fine in swift 1.1. But in 1.2 its breaking.

```
class AboutViewController_Tests: XCTestCase
{
//var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)) // Used in swift 1.1

var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle()) // Replaced this in swift 1.2
var aboutViewController:AboutViewController!

override func setUp()
{
super.setUp()
aboutViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController
aboutViewController.viewDidLoad()
XCTAssertNotNil(aboutViewController, "About not nil")
}
}
```

**Error while running the unit test**

*Could not cast value of type 'testProject.AboutViewController' (0x105b0ad30) to 'testProjectTests.AboutViewController' (0x116e51d20).*

I have done enough research to resolve this issue. But couldn't able to do it. I hope some of you come across this problem and will able to help me here.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and solution is:

- Add storyboard `Main` and `AboutViewController` in test target
- Replace `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())` with 
  `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder))`

This way you'll load storyboard and initialize controller from test target bundle, instead from using it from main target bundle.
[Check this link for details](http://www.iosmike.com/2014/08/unit-testing-viewcontrollers-in-swift.html)

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same problem a few minutes ago. Here's how i solved it.

1. Add storyboard to the testing target
2. Load the view controller this way:

```
var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))

self.vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("gettingStartedView") as! MainViewController

self.vc.loadView()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This change fixed it for me too

Answer (score 1):

> Try this it worked

```
class VehicleListControllerSpecs: XCTestCase {

var listController: VehicleListController!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VehicleListController") as! VehicleListController
listController = vc
    _ = listController.view
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

func testListViewHasTableView() {
    XCTAssertNotNil(listController.tableView,"view doesnt has tableview")
}
}
```